# Permission don't work as expected - PowerShell works, GUI doesn't

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, permissions, powershell, windows-command-prompt, accounts

I'm a software developer and not really into all those server config things... still I have a problem that really confuses me. I'll try to explain it as good as I can:

When I log into a server with a specific account, I don't have the permission to access C:\ - Also I don't have permissions to do something in the console. When I try to access C:\ per explorer, I get the following error message:

> Accessing the resource 'C:\' has been disallowed.

When I open a console (cmd):

> The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator.

Until here everything is fine. I thought that the account simply doesn't have the permission to do these tasks.

Now the weird part:
When I create a file on C:\ with a PowerShell Script it works...

```
PS C:\> New-Item -Path "C:\test" -Name "testfile1.cmd" -ItemType "file" -Value "cd\"
```

This works perfectly. When I run the testfile1.cmd via powershell, it also prints me the expected result. Can someone explain me why I can't do all these things trough the GUI, neither have access to the normal console, but can make it work with powershell?

As said, I don't know that much about permissions on systems since I come from the software part, so I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint - sounds like group policy

Comment: Yes, this is Group Policy. Blocking access to the command prompt adds zero security and is a holdover from the days before access control. IMO it serves no useful purpose anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is because either a local security policy or group policy object configured “Prevent access to drives from My Computer” to Enabled.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8035/how-to-restrict-access-to-drive-in-my-computer-on-windows/

Your second error is because because either a local security policy or group policy object configured “Prevent access to the command prompt” to enabled.

These are security policies set by your administrator. You should discuss your questions with your administrator and/or supervisor (whichever combination of people is appropriate for your employer).

Answer (score 0):

> This works perfectly. When I run the testfile1.cmd via powershell, it
>   also prints me the expected result. Can someone explain me why I can't
>   do all these things trough the GUI, neither have access to the normal
>   console, but can make it work with powershell?

Those restrictions block interactive, but not programmatic, access to those components.